# SSRS Display Chart next to Table when row selected

Tags: reporting-services, charts

I have a table of Technicians which I have then linked to a Chart via `Action` and then `Go to Report`. I then selected my current report as the chart is on my current report. The chart is hidden until I Select a Technician Name from my table. This is taking very long and it looks like a new report is opening. Have I linked this correctly or is there another way to link a chart to a table when they are in the same report?

The properties setting:

[image: Properties Settings]

#### Expected results

[image: Expected results]

Comment: "Go to Report..." opens a new report.  I think that what you want is a sub-report.

Comment: Are you trying to show a single chart that will update as you click on each technician record? If so then that's not possible directly. Explain a bit more, or show a sketch of expected output and I'll see if I can come up with a possible workaround.

Comment: Hi @AlanSchofield. I attached an imagine under the `Text Box Properties` image and I named it "Expected results". Can you see it? That is the results I am trying to achieve. And yes correct, when I click on a single Technician, I expect to see his results only in the chart. Let me know if you need further info. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you stick with what SSRS gives you out of the box then I don't think you can do what you are trying. As you noticed, when you do "go to report" it basically reloads the report from scratch, hence why it's slow.

The closest I could get was to create the chart as a subreport, add this to the main report in a new column and toggle visibility based on person name.

Below is a report I built that should be simple to adapt to your data if you decide it's suitable.

In case you are interested, I got this data from the WideWorldImporters.

I grabbed some basic data consisting of 'category', 'person', 'date' and 'amount' so structurally it should equate roughly to your screen shot in the finished report.

So first I created a report called `_sub_chart`. This takes a single `personID` as its parameter and produces a single chart like this

[image]

I then created the main report (the query was identical as I'm lazy just no WHERE clause).

The report is a simple table with parent group for `CustomerCategoryName`.

The detail row is hidden and visibility toggled by the `CustomerCategoryName` textbox (which is what you are already doing it seems).

I then appended a column and at the detail level, inserted a subreport. The subreport is set to point to the subreport created earlier and the parameter is set to personID field.

[image]

Finally I set the chart to be hidden and toggled visibility based on the **`Fullname`** textbox.

The final design looks like this.

[image]

When I first open the report it looks like this...

[image]

Clicking one of the categories gives us this.

[image]

and finally, clicking a person gives us this....

[image]

**Note:** Other than the less than pretty layout, this design cannot automatically collapse one name when you click on another so you can end up with lots of charts visible unless you collapse them once viewed.

Performance should be pretty good though so it might be a workaround for you.

To avoid the ugly gaps between names you could add a new detail row, merge the cells from fullname to ordercount and put the chart there instead. The chart would be stacked under the persons details but it a bit more compact and neater (imho) this way.

Anyway, I hope this was helpful - good luck

Comment: Thanks a lot Alan - I am going to try this out.